# How to configure gedit as git core.editor?

Tags: git, gedit

I have gedit configured as git core.editor.

```
git config --global core.editor "gedit"
```

This works fine unless there is already a gedit windows open. In that case, COMMIT_EDITMSG is opened in the existing window and gedit returns immediately. Git ends up with an empty commit message and fails.

This site (http://fabianschuiki.wordpress.com/2012/05/20/use-gedit-as-git-editor/) suggests using "gedit -s -w", but I don't have those options (and --new-window doesn't work):

```
$ gedit -V
gedit - Version 2.28.4

$ gedit --help
Usage:
  gedit [OPTION...] [FILE...] - Edit text files

Help Options:
  -h, --help                      Show help options
  --help-all                      Show all help options
  --help-gtk                      Show GTK+ Options
  --help-sm-client                Show session management options

Application Options:
  -V, --version                   Show the application's version
  --encoding=ENCODING             Set the character encoding to be used to open the files listed on the command line
  --list-encodings                Display list of possible values for the encoding option
  --new-window                    Create a new toplevel window in an existing instance of gedit
  --new-document                  Create a new document in an existing instance of gedit
  --display=DISPLAY               X display to use
```

Answer (score 34):

All credit to VonC answer, but the `-w` makes gedit (3.18) crash on my ubuntu 16.04. Works fine without though:

```
git config --global core.editor "gedit -s"
```

Comment: Interesting to know. +1

Comment: It only crashes when you combine -w and -s. Both -w and -s work when used independently. But it seems that -s implies -w...

Comment: Both answers were valid, but this worked on Ubuntu 19.x

Answer (score 27):

The simplest way to solve this would be to upgrade `gedit` (which is at 3.8.3 with an Ubuntu 13.10)

In 3.x, `-s` (standalone) and `-w` (wait) are available.
That allows for (as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19455929/how-to-configure-gedit-as-git-core-editor/19457491#comment50921250_19457491) by [Fortisimo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/103824/fortisimo)):

```
git config --global core.editor "gedit -w -s"
```

As [Gábor Lipták](https://stackoverflow.com/users/337621/g%C3%A1bor-lipt%C3%A1k) comments [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19455929/how-to-configure-gedit-as-git-core-editor/19457491?noredirect=1#comment59172311_19457491), this works with gedit3, which is installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install gedit-common/trusty 
sudo apt-get install gedit/trusty
```

(on Linux Mint)

Comment: @Fortisimo good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: To install gedit 3 for linux mint:
sudo apt-get install gedit-common/trusty
sudo apt-get install gedit/trusty

Comment: @GáborLipták is it still called `gedit`? Does the config works in that case?

Comment: Yep the config above works only with gedit 3. With gedit 2 it throws an error, that -w is not known as argument. The APT command above installs gedit 3 on a linux mint mate 17.3.

Comment: @GáborLipták Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: From my tests, only `-s` is required.

Comment: @Jocelyndelalande "which makes it compatible with gedit": you mean compatible with gedit 2 as opposed to gedit 3?

Comment: @vonc Yep, sorry, but that was wrong. Failed on my side, I since edited to state something true :-).

Comment: I had the same issue on Ubuntu 18.10. Using just `-s` works perfectly for me as well. Thanks @VonC

Answer (score 2):

for those interested:
under ubuntu 18 gedit with -w is crashing under a segfault

[image]

but with -s is charming fine

so please do:

> git config --global core.editor "gedit -s"