# Merge branch 'master' Can't git pull

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, github

hello I have linux mint and when I type and press enter terminal always show this dialog how can I fix this problem
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's `nano`–a text editor–and it is used as default commit message editor in git. To close it is very simple: press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>X</kbd> same time. What you see in the screenshot is a commit message on a merge commit (because of the `git pull`).

If you want to change it into another editor, you have to run:

```
git config --global core.editor "vim"
```

...and additionally set the `GIT_EDITOR` environment variable:

```
export GIT_EDITOR=vim
```

(put this in `~/.bashrc`)

The above will set `vim` as editor. If you want something visual, you may want to try `gedit`:

```
git config --global core.editor "gedit -w -s"
```

- [How do I make Git use the editor of my choice for commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2596805/1420197)
- [How to configure gedit as git core.editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19455929/1420197)

Answer (score 1):

In short

```
CTRL-O CTRL-X
```

The long version: you have local and remote changes. Git pull merges origin/branch with your current branch. Whey you do this, git wants to make a merge commit. You can type a commit message or simply use the default one (by typing the above commands)